# Delete line from files

Tags: shell, files, scripting

I have 8 files in a folder. If any of these files has 2 lines I need to remove the second line from that file. If a file has more than 2 lines then then I do not need to do anything to it.

Comment: Please include what you tried next time. You are just asking someone else to make something for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `find` and `sed`:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c '[[ $(sed -n $= $0) -eq 2 ]]' {} \; -exec sed -i '1!d' {} +
```

Note: `find` should be tweaked with `PATH` and `-maxdepth` depending on the directory structure.

Comment: Hi this is working fine and out put is as i need... thank you...  
can i specify what files to reed 
i need to perform this only on file name starts with " ELL-* " where can i add this in above line

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @deepuu You might want to take a look at the man page of `find`. You can add `find -name "ELL-*" -type f ...` to only process given files.

Comment: hi i tried this

find -name "$PMTargetFileDir/mfg/ELL-*" -type f -exec sh -c '[[ $(sed -n $= $0) -eq 2 ]]' {} \; -exec sed -i '1!d' {} +

but it is not going to that Path tosearch files with ELL-*

and i am very new to Unix

Comment: You should use `find /your/target/directory -name "ELL-*" -type f ...`

Comment: Thanks Team It was fine and all working as expected....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

try this script it works fine.

```
for file in $(ls *.txt)
do
    LINENUMB=`wc -l $file | cut -f1 -d' '`
    if [[ $LINENUMB == 2 ]]; then
    sed -i '$d' $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: hi i tried running this it giving erroe as command not found

Comment: @deepuu it works fine for me, could you please show me that error!!